# Importing a C DLL's functions into a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, interop

I have a 3rd party library that's written in C. It exports all of its functions to a DLL.

I have the .h file, and I'm trying to load the DLL from my C++ program.

The first thing I tried was surrounding the parts where I #include the 3rd party lib in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and, at the end

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

But the problem there was, all of the DLL file function linkage looked like this in their header files:

```
a_function = (void *)GetProcAddress(dll, "a_function");
```

While really `a_function` had type `int (*a_function) (int *)`.  Apparently MSVC++ compiler doesn't like this, while MSVC compiler does not seem to mind.

So I went through (brutal torture) and fixed them all to the pattern

```
typedef int (*_x_a_function) (int *); // using _a_function will not work, C uses it!
_x_a_function a_function ;
```

Then, to link it to the DLL code, in main():

```
a_function = (_x_a_function)GetProcAddress(dll, "a_function");
```

This SEEMS to make the compiler MUCH, MUCH happier, but it STILL complains with this final set of 143 errors, each saying for each of the DLL link attempts:

```
error LNK2005: _x_a_function already defined in main.obj    main.obj
```

Multiple symbol definition errors.. sounds like a job for `extern`!  SO I went and made ALL the function pointer declarations as follows:

### function_pointers.h

```
  typedef int (*_x_a_function) (int *);
  extern _x_a_function a_function ;
```

And in a cpp file:

### function_pointers.cpp

```
  #include "function_pointers.h"
  _x_a_function a_function ;
```

ALL fine and dandy.. except for linker errors now of the form:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _a_function main.obj
```

Main.cpp includes "function_pointers.h", so it should know where to find each of the functions..

I am bamboozled.  Does any one have any pointers to get me functional?  (Pardon the pun..)

Comment: What you are doing sounds OK in principle.  I think the problem may be with how you are trying to build/link the project.  Can you give us some details on this?

Comment: Can you add the extern "C" around the typedef and remove the extern _a_function a_function ?

Comment: So let me just clarify what you've got.  You have the extern "C"  block around the #include for the library header file and in the linking section you are linking against the C library.  The Source code for the DLL library is not included in your project I hope.  Can't do both.

Comment: Yes, I do not have the source for the dll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linker errors like that suggest you've defined all the functions in function_pointers.cpp, but forgotten to add it to the project/makefile.

Either that, or you've forgotten to "extern C" the functions in function_pointers.cpp too.

Comment: Ah, you are super-genius.  I was using Visual Studio and the file was part of the project, but I __didn't__ put an extern declaration around the .c file.  I thought having it in the .h file would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you declare a function in yourlibrary.h like `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl factorial(int);` then create that function in yourlibrary.c:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl factorial(int x) {    
    if(x == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
}
```

After compiling your DLL you get your .dll and .lib files. The latter is used when you want to import your functions to the project. You put `#include "yourlibrary.h"` and `#pragma comment(lib, "yourlibrary.lib")` in your project, after this you can use `int factorial(int)` in you application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you declared the typedefs and/or the prototype as extern "C", you must remember to extern "C" the definition too.

Answer (score 1):

When you link C functions the prototypes will get a leading _ in front of them by default so
when you do a typedef using the same name

```
typedef int (*_a_function) (int *);
_a_function a_function
```

you'll get issues because there is already a function in the dll named _a_function.

Comment: You are right.  This was one issue, and I corrected it to using a leading `_x_` instead.